# Animation "sometimes" spins wrong way

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, uiviewanimation

I have a 16 position wheel that I want to rotate to a random position.  My code makes the wheel spin 3 full times and then stop at a random position.  This seems to work fine except that sometimes the wheel will spin anti-clockwise for the first part of the spin.  I want it to spin clockwise at all times.  My code is shown below.  Any help on where I am going wrong?  I have split the frames into 9, but have tried splitting it into 3, 6, 9 12 etc.

```
//  Generate random numbered position to spin to (1 to 16)
spinto = Int(arc4random_uniform(16) + 1)

//  Make Wheel spin 3 full times, then stop at random position
spin =  CGFloat(M_PI * 6) + (CGFloat((M_PI * 2) / 16) * CGFloat(spinto))

anglelabel.text = "\(self.spin)"

// Animate the wheel spin
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(3.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.CalculationModePaced, animations: {

    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 1/9, animations: {
        self.wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1/9 * self.spin)
    })
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(1/9, relativeDuration: 1/9, animations: {
        self.wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(2/9 * self.spin)
    })

    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(2/9, relativeDuration: 1/9, animations: {
        self.wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3/9 * self.spin)
    })

    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(3/9, relativeDuration: 1/9, animations: {
        self.wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(4/9 * self.spin)
    })

    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(4/9, relativeDuration: 1/9, animations: {
        self.wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(5/9 * self.spin)
    })

    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(5/9, relativeDuration: 1/9, animations: {
        self.wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(6/9 * self.spin)
    })

    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(6/9, relativeDuration: 1/9, animations: {
        self.wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(7/9 * self.spin)
    })

    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(7/9, relativeDuration: 1/9, animations: {
        self.wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(8/9 * self.spin)
    })

    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(8/9, relativeDuration: 1/9, animations: {
        self.wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(9/9 * self.spin)
    })


    }, completion: {finished in

        // do next bit of code
})
```

Comment: Tested the code and it always turns clockwise. are you doing anything else to the wheel? more code would probably help.

Comment: Hi, that is all of the code apart from the variable declarations.  It definitely turns anti-clockwise (up to half a turn) before then spinning clockwise on my system, about 30% of the time.  I have noticed it always works properly on the first spin after running the code.